# Okta introspect method returning bad request

Tags: okta

trying to post to the introspect method is throwing a bad request error:

```
"Bad request.  Accept and/or Content-Type headers likely do not match supported values."
```

here is the url I am hitting

```
..oauth2/v1/introspect?token_type_hint=access&token={token}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={ClientSecret}"
```

I am setting the content-type and accept headers to "application/json"

If those are incorrect there is no documentation stating what they should be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Content-Type needed to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: this is not working for me. granted my app is angular wrapped with cordova running on an android emulate, but I keep getting this error even though it works with postman.

Comment: For reference, this should only be required if sending token via body, not headers. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750